# Converting SOCKS5 Connection to SSL: SSL Error during Handshake Operation - Seeking Assistance

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, https, socks5

I have implemented a SOCKS5 server in Python and I want to intercept and handle messages over WSS (WebSocket over SSL) with my own certificate. However, I encountered an issue when executing .wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True) before the client hello. It is throwing an SSL error with the message “ssl-ssl-error-ssl-wrong-version-number”, followed by a timeout during the handshake operation (“_ssl.c:985: The handshake operation timed out”). But, I am certain that my certificate and TLS protocol version are correct. So, I wanted to ask if it is possible to convert a SOCKS5 connection to SSL. If it is possible, can you help me understand the reason for this error?

I have tried using all available TLS protocol versions, but none of them work. I would like to be able to intercept and handle WSS messages within the SOCKS5 server (with a valid certificate).

```py
   def establish_socks5(self, sock):
       dest_host, dest_port = None, None
       try:
           ver, nmethods, methods = sock.recv(1), sock.recv(1), sock.recv(1)
           sock.sendall(VER + METHOD)
           ver, cmd, rsv, address_type = sock.recv(1), sock.recv(1), sock.recv(1), sock.recv(1)
           dst_addr = None
           dst_port = None
           if address_type == ADDR_TYPE_IPV4:
               dst_addr, dst_port = sock.recv(4), sock.recv(2)
               dst_addr = '.'.join([str(chr_to_int(i)) for i in dst_addr])
           elif address_type == ADDR_TYPE_DOMAIN:
               addr_len = ord(sock.recv(1))
               dst_addr, dst_port = sock.recv(addr_len), sock.recv(2)
               dst_addr = ''.join([chr(chr_to_int(i)) for i in dst_addr])
           elif address_type == ADDR_TYPE_IPV6:
               dst_addr, dst_port = sock.recv(16), sock.recv(2)
               tmp_addr = []
               for i in range(len(dst_addr) // 2):
                   tmp_addr.append(chr(dst_addr[2 * i] * 256 + dst_addr[2 * i + 1]))
               dst_addr = ':'.join(tmp_addr)
           dst_port = chr_to_int(dst_port[0]) * 256 + chr_to_int(dst_port[1])
           server_sock = sock
           server_ip = ''.join([chr(int(i)) for i in socket.gethostbyname("172.16.8.151").split('.')])
           if cmd == CMD_TYPE_TCP_BIND:
               print('TCP Bind requested, but is not supported by socks5_server')
               sock.close()
           elif cmd == CMD_TYPE_UDP:
               print('UDP requested, but is not supported by socks5_server')
               sock.close()
           elif cmd == CMD_TYPE_CONNECT:
               sock.sendall(VER + SUCCESS + b'\x00' + b'\x01' + encode_str(server_ip +
                                                                           chr(9001 // 256) + chr(
                   9001 % 256)))
               dest_host, dest_port = dst_addr, dst_port
           else:
               # Unsupport/unknown Command
               print('Unsupported/unknown SOCKS5 command requested')
               sock.sendall(VER + UNSUPPORTED_CMD + encode_str(server_ip + chr(9001 // 256) +
                                                               chr(9001 % 256)))
               sock.close()
       except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
           print('Error in SOCKS5 establishment: %s' % e)

       return dest_host, dest_port

   def decorateSocket(self, sock):
    try:
       sslsock = self.context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True)
       return sslsock
    except ssl.SSLError as e:
          print(e)
          return None
 
   sock, address = self.serversocket.accept()
   self.establish_socks5(sock)
   newsock = self.decorateSocket(sock)
   newsock.setblocking(0)
```

Comment: You cannot "convert" SOCKS5 to SSL. What you can do is implement a SOCKS5 server and then SSL intercept any TLS connection which is inside the SOCKS5 tunnel, i.e. starting the SSL handshake for interception after the SOCKS5 handshake is finished. It might be what you mean, it might be not. No useful information are provided of what you really do, i.e. no code, nothing reproducible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have indeed implemented a SOCKS5 server and attempted to perform an SSL handshake after the SOCKS5 handshake, but unfortunately, it has not been successful. Translation: “Yes, I have implemented a SOCKS5 server and performed an SSL handshake after the SOCKS5 handshake, but I haven’t been successful.” 
 @Steffen Ullrich

Comment: A SSL/TLS client using the SOCKS proxy will negotiate its handshake only with the target server on the other end of the tunnel. Even if the SOCKS proxy were to intercept the TLS packets that pass through the tunnel, it can't decrypt them, and it can't fake its own handshake if the client validates the peer it handshakes with (which it should be). SOCKS is just a passthrough, the proxy shouldn't be trying to look at the data that passes through it. The SOCKS protocol doesn't provide for using a separate TLS session with a SOCKS client, it only allows a TLS session to pass through the tunnel

Comment: @wdiwei: again, no code and nothing reproducible but instead only very broad description of what you attempt to do. There is no way to provide actual help with this lack of information. And yes, it is in principle possible to create a TLS intercepting SOCKS5 proxy (and I did it) but this also that the client trusts the certificate provided by the proxy instead of the original certificate of the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: I have already added the code example, could you please help check how to make modifications so it can run normally? plz help!

Comment: @RemyLebeau：I have already added the code example, could you please help check how to make modifications so it can run normally?plz hellp.

Comment: @wdiwei: Have you've first verified that  it works w/o SSL interception, i.e. that the socks protocol is properly spoken and the transfer works? The code is unfortunately not complete enough so I could use it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @wdiwei after calling `context.wrap_socket()`, I don't see you calling `newsock.do_handshake()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau The third parameter of wrap_socket is do_handshake_on_connect, which defaults to True.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The above code can be made to run with a few simple modifications. If you have succeeded before, could you possibly provide a demo?

Comment: @wdiwei yes, that parameter is True by default, but that parameter only applies when you call `connect()` or `accept()` on the SSL socket, which is not the case in this situation since the underlying TCP socket is already accepted before the SSL socket is created to wrap it, so you have to call `do_handshake()` directly to initiate the handshake with the client.

Comment: @wdiwei: *"The above code can be made to run with a few simple modifications."* - then please post the code with the modifications applied. Remember, you want free help from others so make it easy for others. And again, have you succeeded to do SOCKS5 without SSL interception first? Because when this already fails then adding SSL interception on top will fail too. *" If you have succeeded before, could you possibly provide a demo?"* - the code is neither public nor in Python.